# Add negative margin to a div which has a container

Tags: css

So I have a container over my div element, but I can't remove it. I have to adjust the div below so I get rid of the white spaces on left and right using negative margins. However when I am trying to add negative margin from left and right, the div shifts only to left. What am I doing wrong?

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.background {
  height: 650px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  margin: 0px -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background">
    test
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You are adding padding to container, might think to remove it

Comment: `width: 100%;` is based on the available width _inside_ the container, inside the padding. Just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  padding: 0px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.background {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left:0;
right: 0;
bottom:0;
  height: 650px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background">
    test
  </div>

</div>
```